# Storing Scraped Data thro Scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

How do I store entire scraped data in a file? Eg: Data scraped is `[u\ 7564.2021]` but the stored data in a json file is only `[`

Where does it goes wrong?

Comment: Have you had any exceptions during the execution of your spider? Do you actually use the JSON Exporter? Do you actually yield/return your scraped items? ... eg.: it would be useful to see your code and scrapy output.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread because I had this exact issue using the scrapy command line export option (found this in scrapy 0.15.1 Overview: http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/intro/overview.html?highlight=Rule#run-the-spider-to-extract-the-data), "scrapy crawl mininova.org -o scraped_data.json -t json".

You must first ensure that data is actually being scraped from the site (I did this by printing my scraped items right to the console window).

Also ensure sure that your spider's parse method actually returns the scraped item. This was the silly mistake I made.

Without more information or your code it is hard to say more. I am new to Python and scrapy myself, and am working through the sometimes confusing docs and examples. Hope you haven't dropped this project in the past couple months; otherwise I am posting for future googlers.